# Google Sheets: Random Generator Random Errors?

Tags: google-sheets

I have been working on a random character generator for Pathfinder (a D&D like game). I have the generator working pretty well with some advanced features to create dynamic ranges with the =randbetween function. I have it set up to comment out ranges in the list based on toggled check boxes. This works for the most part, sometimes however, the function will return FALSE when it shouldn't but there is no error code and I am having a hard time finding the issue. Here is a basic example of my function.

```
=if(B3=true,index({ 
IF(B5=TRUE,{D5,E5,F5}), 
IF(B6=TRUE,{D6,E6,F6}), 
IF(B7=TRUE,{D7,E7,F7}) 
},randbetween(1,COUNTA({ 
IF(B5=TRUE,{D5,E5,F5}), 
IF(B6=TRUE,{D6,E6,F6}), 
IF(B7=TRUE,{D7,E7,F7}) 
}))),"")
```

Here is a link to the sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YS3ayQxS6vA67dlh61hrr-zJzWdOL5LWZj8_P0Wblko/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The example of the function you provided is working correctly. The one in your sheet is not because you have incorrectly placed `=` symbols before `IF` functions inside arrays with brackets, which is not the correct [syntax](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276).

Change this:

```
=if(B3=true,index({
=IF(B5=TRUE,AlignmentGood),
IF(B6=TRUE,AlignmentNeutral),
IF(B7=TRUE,AlignmentEvil,"No Input")
},randbetween(1,COUNTA({
=IF(B5=TRUE,AlignmentGood),
IF(B6=TRUE,AlignmentNeutral),
IF(B7=TRUE,AlignmentEvil,"No Input")
}))),"No Input")
```

To this:

```
=if(B3=true,index({
IF(B5=TRUE,AlignmentGood),
IF(B6=TRUE,AlignmentNeutral),
IF(B7=TRUE,AlignmentEvil,"No Input")
},randbetween(1,COUNTA({
IF(B5=TRUE,AlignmentGood),
IF(B6=TRUE,AlignmentNeutral),
IF(B7=TRUE,AlignmentEvil,"No Input")
}))),"No Input")
```